# Нужны ли кавычки и большая буква?

Tags: прописная-строчная, пунктуация

Нужны ли кавычки и большая буква в этом предложении (там, где они поставлены)?Правильно ли оно сформировано?

Чтобы настроить устройство, найдите пункт меню "Принтеры" в "Панели управления".

Comment: Если идти по порядку, от общего к частному, как в итоге и получится, то правильнее: Для настройки принтера, откройте последовательно: Панель управления - Устройства и принтеры - Принтеры, и выберите нужную вам модель.

Answer (score 4):

***Чтобы настроить устройство, найдите пункт меню "Принтеры" в панели управления.***

Так как Вы используете слово *пункт*, а затем даёте название этого пункта, выделяя его таким образом из многих, то прописная буква и кавычки в названиии необходимы. А словосочетание *панель управления* можно писать со строчной и без кавычек.

Comment: Екатерина, панель - это название подраздела. Почему вы рекомендуете строчную?

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки, как и прописная буква нужны, это названия.

Comment: :Этого недостаточно. Формулируйте ваше рекомендации более корректно.